# Cannot add multiple adsense codes to one page

Tags: javascript, adsense

I'm trying to add 2 adsense codes to one page. When I do it only one (the first defined) is shown and the page seems to be in endless loading.

Here is the code with example slots and client IDs.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"; 
        google_ad_slot = 111111111;
        google_ad_width = 160;
        google_ad_height = 600;
        //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"; //the same like the first one client
        google_ad_slot = 222222222;
        google_ad_width = 336;
        google_ad_height = 280;
        //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

If I remove one of these adSense codes than it works. How can I make it work with both codes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally after almost 2 hours of googling I figured it out. Only thing I had to do is to add **quotes to google_ad_slot variable** (Oh my...). So the working code looks like this:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"; 
    google_ad_slot = "111111111"; // see the quotes
    google_ad_width = 160;
    google_ad_height = 600;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"; //the same like the first one client
    google_ad_slot = "222222222";
    google_ad_width = 336;
    google_ad_height = 280;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

If there is just one adSense code, the slot as an integer works fine. If **you add another, you must define all slots as strings**.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no need to require the show-ad.js file twice. Secondly it seems that show-ad.js looks at some set global variables

```
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"; 
    google_ad_slot = 111111111;
    google_ad_width = 160;
    google_ad_height = 600;
```

When you define them a second time the first values are dicarted, and the first one is only shown because loading the script a second time interferes with the first.

Comment: You are right that the problem is in rewriting global variables which are used in both banners. I'm not quite sure if there is no need to require the show-ad.js twice. If you look at the file you will find call of one anonymous function. So there is no way how to call it again. Still the problem remains. How to make it work?

Comment: I have searched around a bit and found that it is forbidden to have multiple adsense accounts on one page. I would be careful about this because both accounts can be banned.

Comment: My issue was with one account only. And yes you can add more than one units. "Up to three ad units and three link units may be placed on each page". See https://www.google.com/adsense/policies